# Why is the relativistic Lorentz factor defined this way?

Tags: special-relativity

My question is: why has the [Lorentz factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_factor) the form

$$\gamma = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1 - \dfrac{v^2}{c^2}}}$$

and not, for example one of those:

$$\gamma = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1 - \dfrac{v}{c}}}$$

or

$$\gamma = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1 - \dfrac{v^2}{2 c^2}}}$$

or

$$\gamma = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt[3]{1 - \dfrac{v^2}{c^2}}}$$

Or one of the other many possibilities?

I mean: nobody ever told me where did the definition of $\gamma$ came from. Can you explain it to me?

Comment: Well, it appears in so many equations in special relativity that it appears convenient to define a shorthand for it, no? (In contrast to your other possibilities, which never appear)

Comment: Ok but Where does it comes from? Someone woke up and decided that Gamma is defined like that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I derive the Lorentz contraction from the invariant interval?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/80511/)

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/114372/

Comment: You can derive it from the assumption that the speed of light is the same for all observers; [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_dilation#Simple_inference_of_time_dilation_due_to_relative_velocity) has an accessible derivation.